# In this example, which is a premaster secret, and which is a master secret?

Tags: diffie-hellman, terminology

In the context of this data, as shown in the image below, which one is a pre-master-secret and which one is a master-secret. It looks to me as if the final value of 2, for Alice and Bob is a master-secret which can be then used for creating a symmetric key (AES). Am I right?

> 1. Alice and Bob agree to use a prime number $p=23$ and base $g=5$.
> 2. Alice chooses a secret integer $a=6$, then sends Bob $A=g^a\mod p$
>
>    - $A=5^6\mod 23$
>    - $A=15,625\mod 23$
>    - $A=8$
> 3. Bob chooses a secret integer $b=15$, then sends Alice $B=g^b\mod p$
>
>    - $B=5^{15}\mod 23$
>    - $B=30,517,578,125\mod 23$
>    - $B=19$
> 4. Alice computes $s=B^a\mod p$
>
>    - $s=19^6\mod 23$
>    - $s=47,045,881\mod 23$
>    - $s=2$
> 5. Bob computes $s=A^b\mod p$
>
>    - $s=8^{15}\mod 23$
>    - $s=35,184,372,088,832\mod 23$
>    - $s=2$
> 6. Alice and Bob now share a secret (the number $2$) because $6$ x $15$ is the same as $15$ x $6$.

Comment: This is [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) with artificially small $p$. One thing is misleading: for $p$ of practical interest, that is of some thousand(s) bits, when computing $g^a\bmod p$, one does _not_ computes $g^a$ then reduce $\bmod p$; $g^a$ is simply too huge. Note: I do not know a standard usage of the terms _master key_ or _pre-master key_ in this context.

Comment: If the question is about terminology, I would have to agree with @fgrieu ; the terms "premaster key" and "master key" are not standard terminology; at the least, I've never heard of them either.  It might be terminology someone made up; if so, you'd have to ask them what they meant.  The closest standard terms I can think of is the TLS terms "premaster secret" and "master secret" (which are intermediate values derived during the TLS key exchange protocol, and differ from what you have referenced)

Comment: Okay, assume I meant premaster-secret and master-secret, are they related to the Diffie Helman in any way, because with just RSA as key exchange, there would be no premaster-secret or master-secret. At least this is what Wikipedia depicts in its hadnshake section, which I believe is using the Diffie Helman as Key exchange. Insight is valued.

Answer (score 6):

The protocol outlined in the question is [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) with artificially small $p$. Beware that one thing is misleading in this exposition: for $p$ of practical interest, that is of some thousand(s) bits, when computing $g^a\bmod p$, one does *not* computes $g^a$ then reduce $\bmod p$ as shown, because $g^a$ is too huge. Instead, one reduces $\bmod p$ (at least) after each multiplication. Approximately ${3\over 2}\cdot\log_2a$ modular multiplications are performed in the simplest algorithm used in practice.

Thanks to [poncho's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/in-this-example-which-is-a-pre-master-key-and-which-is-a-master-key#comment-27218), we know that the terms *premaster secret* and *master secret* are used in [TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-8.1), as:

> **8.1. Computing the Master Secret**
>
> For all key exchange methods, the same algorithm is used to convert
> the `pre_master_secret` into the `master_secret`.  The `pre_master_secret`
> should be deleted from memory once the `master_secret` has been
> computed.
>
> ```
>   master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret",
>                       ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)
>                       [0..47];
> ```
>
> The master secret is always exactly 48 bytes in length.  The length
> of the premaster secret will vary depending on key exchange method.
>
> **8.1.1. RSA**
>
> When RSA is used for server authentication and key exchange, a 48-
> byte pre_master_secret is generated by the client, encrypted under
> the server's public key, and sent to the server.  The server uses its
> private key to decrypt the `pre_master_secret`.  Both parties then
> convert the `pre_master_secret` into the `master_secret`, as specified
> above.
>
> **8.1.2. Diffie-Hellman**
>
> A conventional Diffie-Hellman computation is performed.  The
> negotiated key (Z) is used as the `pre_master_secret`, and is converted
> into the `master_secret`, as specified above.  Leading bytes of Z that
> contain all zero bits are stripped before it is used as the
> `pre_master_secret`.
>
> Note: Diffie-Hellman parameters are specified by the server and may
> be either ephemeral or contained within the server's certificate.

---

Thus, in the protocol of the question, which can be seen as a reduced example of Diffie-Hellman as it would be used in TLS, $s$ is the `pre_master_secret`; the `master_secret` would be derived from it.

Comment: This is a great answer -- it clarifies *both* the terminology ("pre-master" / "master" secrets) and the context (e.g., "TLS with DH") where the reference is supposed to make sense in. I think most people with the OP's question are going to be referring to it in that context ---> i.e., specifically TLS with DH-style key exchange too. There may also be a "slight hint" as far as terminology goes that since $A$ and $B$ do not need to be exchanged "secretly", the final result of DH (i.e., $s$) is the first "shared secret" and so is likely going to be the one called "pre-master" in the terminology